# how to make a perl script create a directory and a makefile in the script

Tags: perl

I was going through lessons and i saw a practise saying to make a script that creates a directory and a makefile inside the actual script. i know how to do this in the ubuntu terminal with mkdir but can you actually create in a script? any help on this please?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of coming straight to Stack Overflow for help, it would have been better to have started with some research of your own. I suggest the `perldoc` utility that is installed with Perl. The same information is also available on line at [perldoc.perl.org](http://perldoc.perl.org/)

It sounds like you need—surprise!—the [`mkdir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/mkdir.html) operator, or you could look at the core [`File::Path`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Path) module

As for the make file, you don't say anything about what you need, but a simple `open`, like this will do the trick

```
open my $fh, '>', '/path/to/makefile' or die $!
```

and then you can just `print` what you like to it